# I2S microphone not recognized

Tags: microphone, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu Server 23.10 (without Desktop) in a Raspberry Pi 3.
I have connected INMP441 MEMS Microphones with the RPi according to the tutorial in [here](https://makersportal.com/blog/recording-stereo-audio-on-a-raspberry-pi)

INMP441 uses I2S interface. However, when I ran in terminal

```
arecord -l
```

it does not show any I2S device. I searched different forums and didn't find anything on how to interface I2S microphone (such as INMP441) with Ubuntu. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I2S devices are not autodetected. Have you done any configuration of your system?

Answer (score 1):

Add yourself to the `audio` group with

```
sudo adduser $USER audio
```

Then, logoff and login. Group memberships are applied at `login` time.